# Physics reading material for mathematics grad student

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I am a graduate student in mathematics studying algebraic logic. For quite some time now, I have been meaning to study physics -- it turns out that some ideas in foundations of mathematics have found promising applications in theoretical physics (topos quantum theory and quantum logic come to mind). I want to get a somewhat rigorous picture of classical and quantum mechanics, so that I can contextualize some of the things I will be reading later on. Is there a good resource that I can use for this? I would prefer to read something that has a careful development of ideas starting with classical mechanics, eventually culminating in a broad formulation of quantum mechanics. All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: The only book I know of that really goes from classical to quantum mechanics is the book by Shankar.

Comment: not sure starting with classical is the ideal way to go…

Comment: Could you explain why it is not ideal? My thinking is that it might be instructive to approach quantum mechanics as a refinement of classical mechanics. But then again, I can only speak from limited experience.

Comment: @DanielSank The book by Shankar seems promising, thank you very much!

Comment: it’s not “formal” but you might care to read the early sections of Landau&Lifschitz, where they claim that it “is in principle impossible to formulate the basic concepts of quantum mechanics without using classical mechanics”, even if QM is supposed to supercede CM and should therefore be formulated without CM.  Betting on Landau’s insight is rarely a loosing proposition.

Comment: For a gentle intro for mathematicians: A. Sudbery, Quantum mechanics and the particles of Nature is written with math grad students in mind.

Comment: nicely said: "Betting on Landau’s insight is rarely a loosing proposition"